# Can i use MOSI/MISO pins from this schematic

Tags: arduino, embedded

Can i use MOSI/MISO pins from ATMEGA328 to use for ICSP programmers. I am already using clk and data as inputs to control my 7-segments. I want to use the icsp but i already used the miso/mosi pins for my 7 segment already, does it make sense to have a uC pin be used as outputs for both the 7-segment and the ICSP header.

[image]

Thanks.

Edit: Sorry for the confusion all i have updated  my question.

Comment: I think you may have left out a good chunk of your question. MOSI and MISO (and others) are already used for ISP, and serial programming uses TX and RX.

Comment: I guess it'll depend on the 7seg display. Will they respond to or interfere with data sent from the ICSP programmers when you're trying to program it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FTDI/ICSP programmer? Arent that two different things? FTDI use rx and tx pins, while Atmega ICSP will need your SPI pins.

Anyway, if you are trying to use SPI (miso, mosi, clk, cs) pin for flashing the ATMega (ICSP), that will work. Consider that most SPI based arduino shield - ethernet shield W5100 for example, use these pins (just like your 7 segments) and yet the arduino can still be flashed using the same pins.

Remember that to use ICSP, you will need MOSI, MISO, CLK, and RESET pin as well as vcc gnd to power up the atmega

Comment: The only thing I'd add here is that, when the system is being re-flashed (by the ICSP programmer), whatever's connected to those same signals (ie. your 'Clk' & 'Data' lines) will also see the ICSP programming pulses.  It depends entirely on what that peripheral is, as to whether this matters.  If it's your 7Seg display, maybe it'll do nothing, maybe it'll display gibberish, and maybe that doesn't matter to you. If you were controlling something more physical like a motor/solenoid/etc, then you probably wouldn't want to share these pins in such a manner.

Comment: Thanks and yes it is connected to a 7-segment and i am guessing the pulses sent by the icsp might display gibberish values like you said.